# Insert Image to mysql database in android using PHP

Tags: android, mysql, bitmap

I have a problem to save a image to mysql using PHP.
I have some code but it's got some errors.
Here is my code.

```
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.id.img_upload);
         //img_Photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
         ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); //compress to which format you want.
         byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
         image_str= Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 1);

         postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("photo", image_str));
```

Here, `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);` is always got Null.
My code is wrong or which part should i repair. Give me some advices.

Comment: Imagebutton from xml.

Comment: try `Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);`

Comment: can't change Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr); In my app, Base64 doesn't have encodeBytes();

Comment: @user3032822 Check out my answer and try to change accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Change your line as below:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.img_upload);
```

If you want to get the image from `ImageButton` try out as below:

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
```

Comment: img_upload is Imagebutton. :)

Comment: You can not get the image from the image button in this way. Are you trying to get image from ImageButton ?

Comment: Yes it should be from drawable only not from views.

Comment: Yes, I must store an image from gallery to mysql database. In that case, I also show an image that is from gallery onto the imagebutton.

Comment: You can store the path of your image into the database and can access the images using that path only.

Comment: Can you give me some example or advices.

Comment: You can get the path of your image while you select the image from gallery.

Comment: OK. Would you like to give me some samples,plz?

Comment: Check out this tutorial http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/09/hello-friends-today-i-am-going-to-share.html it will help you. @user3032822

Comment: Also check out http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/12/23/store-image-android-sqlite-retrieve-it/ @user3032822

Comment: The sample you give me is SQLite Database but mine is mysql. Isn't alittle different?

Comment: In android there is only SQLite database used. I don't know how and why you are using mysql. Checkout thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732853/how-to-connect-android-app-to-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

first convert your image  into a base 64 byte array encoded string. after that send it to php. extract on server side.Then store that string in MySQL. after that send that string to android client. extract image string and decode with base 64 decode. after that you will get byte array  you can simply show in your image view. for your reference I will show some code

```
      String imagedata = Base64.encodeToString(thumbnailArray,Base64.DEFAULT);
            mJobject.put("imagebyte",imagedata);
              mJArray.put(mJobject);

            JSONArray json=new JSONArray(response);
            JSONObject jo = null;

           imageArray=new String[json.length()];

         imageArray[i]=jo.getString("imageid");

          completeImage= Base64.decode(imageArray[0],Base64.DEFAULT); 
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(completeImage , 0, completeImage.length);
```