# Using same DB records with Sqlite and MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I am developing an android app as junior project at school.

It is a simple TVGuide. I have parsed program names, dates, times etc with Java and I've inserted this parsed texts to DB with mysql.

On the other hand , I want to use sqlite in android part of my project while fetching the parsed records.

So, how can I use parsed contents from mysql in sqlite. I have created DB with MySQL. I am not sure can I use same db with sqlite. 
Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the community. The SQLite and MySQL databases are different programs. if you want to create a duplicate SQLite database you can, but you cannot just setup SQLite to use the MySQL records, which I think is what you are asking.

If this is for a school project and you don't have to use SQLite and you already have the MySQL db then it may be easier for you to just use that. perhaps with PHP on a local server. That possibility has been explored here on SO before [Android PHP MySQL Combo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732853/how-to-connect-android-app-to-mysql-database) .

if you are still interested in using SQLite for your project you can find a tutorial it [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Hope that helps.