# Best way to access SQL on Android app

Tags: android, mysql

I'm new to android app developing. I have a MySQL database online and I want do create an app that show some information that are on this database. I don't know Java.

Which is the best way to do this? Learning Java, creating a PHP webpage and show it on the app screen, ...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect Android app to MySQL database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732853/how-to-connect-android-app-to-mysql-database)

Comment: It sounds like you are have design questions. Perhaps you should try on [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). Design and architecture is on-topic according to their [Help Center](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"best" is highly subjective.  I personally would recommend learning Java, since the SDKs and all the example code are written in it.  Also, with Cordova, you are writing javascript anyway, so why not just make the leap to Java.

Here is a tutorial with PHP, MySQL and Java Android app connecting to it:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

I worked on my app with RESTful access its very easy and efficient. But in my case i was working with JCR and sling. You don't need to know java to use this.