# how to connect from android to mysql in nodejs server?

Tags: android, mysql, node.js, express

I'm making an application, I already have a website nodejs with expressjs framework and mysql database. how to process the input, update and delete data from android to mysql without using php server side?  if anyone has ever made before? thank you

Comment: You can make the RESTFull APIs and access those APIs from Android.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732853/how-to-connect-android-app-to-mysql-database

Answer (score 1):

Basicly that's what the server side code is doing! 
Handling all the data and requests between the two (android app & the relational database)
Any attempt to not use the PhP or any type of language for that matter would cause only to iconically change some data from the app! 
But that's not the case since you want to alter also the database as you clearly mention!

As for the how: The only way to use the data transfer to the app is by the use of json packets! 
A exchange should be made between the app and the database "through" the server side php code and they should exchange json files with data! 
Then your problem is solved.