# how can android app read data from database on the server?

Tags: android, database, server

I have database on a server, and I have the username and password to access to this server. 
My question is: how can my android app read a table from a database on a server?
I know, this question was asked, but I did not found any code or any answer that explain that detailed.

Comment: You need to write a web server that exposes the data.

Comment: There are actually several ways of doing this, it would help if you wrote down what you tried to do and where it didn't work out for you.

Comment: @SLaks Can you give me an exmaple or any tutorial? 
or in which language should i write that? and how?

Comment: @Razgriz I need only one column from this database, I have all things(hostname, username, password and server) but I do not how to use that or how to write a program that does that:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need a Web Service that read/write into your DB. Android then read the data through JSONObject and parser.

Direct connection through JDBC is insecure.

Below is tutorial on How Android connect to mySql on server

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm
- http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database
- http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

You may also take a look on this thread

- [How to connect Android app to MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732853/how-to-connect-android-app-to-mysql-database)

Comment: thanx, is JDBC easier? If yes, then can you give me tutorials of that, because the security is at the moment not very important for me. I need to write my program only in java, I do not need php.

Comment: It is doable https://capdroid.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/configuring-and-accessing-mysql-jdbc-driver-on-android-application/ BUT not very recommended. Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233145/connecting-to-mysql-from-android-with-jdbc